# Running two command prompt terminals in native windows, how can I redirect the output of one to the input of the other?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have one Windows 10 command prompt running and awaiting input, and I wish to automate continuous and live input with a second command prompt. I have gotten the second command prompt to extract the desired variable, and I wish to send it to the other command prompt that is waiting for input.

The "awaiting input" command prompt must run in real time because it is connected to Plink  (not an SSH session so no use of the -m command here) which is connecting to a microcontroller. So it cannot be accomplished (at least I don't think) with function calls.

I see that it can be done in UNIX environments: https://askubuntu.com/questions/496914/write-command-in-one-terminal-see-result-on-other-one

Thanks in advance and please advise,

--A hopeful beginner

Comment: May I misunderstood you, but this sample answer may help you

Comment: No simple way, but it is possible. Have a look at [Send commands to a cmd window through a .bat file - Rejected StackOverflow question](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078) on DosTips.

Answer (score 0):

Batch code starts 2 piped processes, one for getting keyboard input and writing to a file, and the other reading the data written. Note there isn't a cmd window for each process, but there are two new processes running. You may use `cmd /c` or `start` if you need two consoles.

Does it help?

```
@echo off

set "pipefile=pipefile.txt"

if "%~1" neq "" goto %1

copy nul "%pipefile%" >nul
"%~F0" getInput >>"%pipefile%" | "%~F0" readInput <"%pipefile%"
echo(
echo(Batch end...
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
del /F /Q "%pipefile%" 2>nul
exit/B



:getInput
set "input="
set/P "input="<CON
echo(%input%
if /I "%input%" equ "EXIT" exit
goto:getInput


:readInput
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set/P="enter some data [EXIT to exit] "
for /l %%. in () do (
  set "input="
  set/P "input="
  if defined input (
    if /I "!input!" equ "EXIT" exit
    set/P="enter some data [EXIT to exit] "
  )
   ping 1.1.1.1 -w 10 -n 1 >nul 2>nul & rem avoid processor load (may be removed) 
)
```

Running two console windows

```
@echo off

set "pipefile=pipefile.txt"

if "%~1" neq "" goto %1

del /F /Q "%pipefile%" 2>nul
copy nul "%pipefile%" >nul

start "writer" cmd /c ^""%~f0" readInput ^<"%pipefile%" ^"
start "reader" cmd /c ^""%~f0" getInput ^"

echo(
Echo batch end...
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
goto :EOF


:getInput
set "input="
set/P "input=enter some data [EXIT to exit] "
echo(%input%>>"%pipefile%"
if /I "%input%" equ "EXIT" exit
goto:getInput

:readInput
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%. in () do (
  set "input="
  set /p "input="
  if defined input (
    if /I "!input!" equ "EXIT" exit
    echo(!input!
  )
   ping 1.1.1.1 -w 10 -n 1 >nul 2>nul & rem avoid processor load (may be removed) 
)
```

Comment: Nice, but you are assuming the OP's target process is a batch script that can be modified to endlessly look for input until it sees a command to exit. It might be a pre-existing exe utility or batch script that cannot be modified, in which case it will probably terminate early if it reaches the end of the file before the first process has had a chance to write the next line. See [Send commands to a cmd window through a .bat file - Rejected StackOverflow question](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078) on DosTips for a way to extend your idea to work in most any scenario.

Comment: @dbenham Nice sample, I'll keep in mind thinking in more open scenarios in the future.