# simulate keyboard input to batch file via file and pipe on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

the title might be slightly confusing but what I need is a method to hand over pre-configured parameters to a batchfile on windows commandline.

The batchflie executes several progams (openssl) that need interactive input. To avoid this, I wrote all necessary input parameters to a textflie and now try to do something like:

```
type parameters.txt | mybatchfile.bat
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: does this help? https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078

Comment: or, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419420/running-two-command-prompt-terminals-in-native-windows-how-can-i-redirect-the-o/39449497#39449497

Comment: Hmmm ... the solutions seem way to complex for me, even if it might help. So I'd probably rather simulate keyboard strokes with python.

Answer (score 0):

Passing text into stdin of interactive prompts of console programs sometimes works, but needs to be done on single line of specific program. Tested way for SSH communication in batch file:

```
some batch code
echo n| plink.exe -pw "somepassword" root@somehost someremotecommand
some batch code
```

https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/plink.exe